# Spark streaming how to immediately operate data with mapWithState

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I want to accept TV data and do some operations

First I create a Class as datatype

```
class Customer(val customerID: Int, val TimeStamp: Int, val Channel: Int)
```

when the streaming receive data, I turned it to RDD[k,v] type, k is customerID+TimeStamp,and then vlue is the Customer object

The first question is how to use mapWithState to collect all data ?
(so that I can do some operation like statistics)

and the seconed is if I have a function

```
rateLookup(Channel, TimeStamp)
```

to list all the data with the same Channel and TimeStamp

how to let user trigger this function while the streaming is running?

Could the streaming detect user input and then excute the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first question is how to use mapWithState to collect all data?

You need to use `StateSpec.function` to create the matching function for `mapWithState`:

```
def analyzeCustomer(customerId: Int, 
                    data: Option[Seq[Customer]], 
                    state: State[Customer]): Option[Customer] = {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Where the `State[T]` is the state of the data you'll be keeping in memory, data is what you'll be receiving from the `DStream`. Now call it like this:

```
val spec = StateSpec.function(analyzeCustomer _)
rdd.mapWithState(spec)
```

> how to let user trigger this function while the streaming is running?

There are many ways you can do this. One would be to output the state into a persistent data store and then have the user interface operate from the persistent storage. This can be done with `foreachRDD`:

```
rdd.mapWithState(spec)
   .foreachRDD(rdd => {
        // Output state to persistent storage.
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really helpful. Is there any other way in second question that can read data directly in memory instead of disk I/O ?

Comment: You can output the data to a some kind of caching mechanism, like [Redis](http://redis.io), if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thank u, I will try it later.